# issues with php file handling

Tags: php, html, forms, file-handling

Please ignore the "read" select option. I am still learning write and append for now. and I wanted to come up with a script that does those two things for me for now before I add more functionality to it. But the error message, that has been displayed below(check the "Error message" picture please) just won't go away.

```
<?php

    $file_handler = fopen('list_of_names.txt', $choice);

    if(isset($_POST['action'])){

        $choice = $_POST['action'];
        echo $choice;

    }

    if(isset($_POST['name'])){
        $enterd_name = $_POST['name'];
        if(!empty($_POST['name'])){
            fwrite($file_handler, $enterd_name."\n");
        }
    }

    fclose($file_handler);

?>

<form action="file_handling.php" method="POST">

    <label for="name">Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="name"><br><br>

    <select name="action">
        <option value="a">Append</option>
        <option value="w">re-write</option>
        <option value="r">read</option>
    </select><br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

[Error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IbPD.png)

Comment: Move $file_handler = fopen... below isset. You are using choice before setting it

Comment: The fopen is probably failing due to file permissions.

Comment: @danielson317 Still the same mate.

Comment: Place all your php code inside this if statement:
  if (isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) && ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'))
  {
    // Submit code here.
  }

Comment: `$choice = $_POST['action'];
$file_handler = fopen('list_of_names.txt', $choice);
if (!$file_handler)
{
  die('File does not exist.');
}
fwrite()
fclose()`

Comment: [Please don't add "solved" to your title or question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/248627). Instead, [mark an answer correct by clicking on the checkmark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/248627). You can also [add your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept it if none of the ones you received solved your problem. Also, please don't SHOUT. If you need to emphasize something you can [do it with Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).